# Flutter doctor: Unable to download dart sdk,BITS service failed in windows

Tags: android-studio, flutter, sdk

error showing:

```
Downloading the Dart SDK using the BITS service failed, retrying with WebRequest...
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At C:\src\flutter\bin\internal\update_dart_sdk.ps1:68 char:5
+     Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $dartSdkUrl -OutFile $dartSdkZip
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Please, I need help I'm new in flutter.

Comment: Are you behind a PROXY ? Please check this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13557

Answer (score 3):

use VPN and try running the command again. it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

You need to have access to internet and run then run

```
flutter doctor
```

from the command line or terminal. It should download the Dart SDK and some other tools.

My output after running flutter doctor:

[image: flutter doctor from command line]

Answer (score 1):

Don't run an elevated command prompt - run it as a user command prompt instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly run in terminal:

```
export PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://pub.flutter-io.cn
export FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL=https://storage.flutter-io.cn
```

then dart sdk download successfully in my MAC.

You have to add `PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://pub.flutter-io.cn` && `FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL=https://storage.flutter-io.cn` in environment.
Try again.

Comment: Which environment would you prefer? User variable or System variable?

Answer (score 0):

just use cmd with administrator and run flutter doctor .
it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:
1- Just use "cmd" as administrator and run "flutter doctor".
2- If you still get the error, open your VPN and try again the step 1.
You will be certainly succeeded.

Answer (score -1):

Simply run

> Flutter doctor

in the PowerShell as administrator.
I hope this resolves your issue :).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).